# Understanding Partition

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

I came across the difficulty of understanding the logic of interaction of the fourth and fifth arguments of `Partition`.

Here is an example:

```
l = Range[7];
p1 = Partition[l, 2, 1, {-1, 1}, {a}]
p2 = Partition[l, 2, 1, {-1, 1}, {a, b}]
p3 = Partition[l, 2, 1, {-1, 1}, {a, b, c}]
p4 = Partition[l, 2, 1, {-1, 1}, {a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> {{a, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, a}}
>
> {{b, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, b}}
>
> {{c, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, b}}
>
> {{d, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, {7, d}}
> ```

What is the logic behind padding the list from the right? Why both in `p2` and `p3` the last element is `b`? Why at the same time in `p4` the last element is `d`?

Similarly, please explain the following:

```
p5 = Partition[l, 3, 1, {-1, 1}, {a, b}]
p6 = Partition[l, 3, 1, {-1, 1}, {a, b, c}]
p7 = Partition[l, 3, 1, {-1, 1}, {a, b, c, d}]
p8 = Partition[l, 3, 1, {-1, 1}, {a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 1}, {b, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, b}, {7, b, a}}
>
> {{b, c, 1}, {c, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, b}, {7, b, c}}
>
> {{c, d, 1}, {d, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, d}, {7, d, a}}
>
> {{d, e, 1}, {e, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, c}, {7, c, d}}
> ```

And also this:

```
p9  = Partition[l, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {a, b}]
p10 = Partition[l, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {a, b, c}]
p11 = Partition[l, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {a, b, c, d}]
p12 = Partition[l, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> ```
> {{b, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, b}}
>
> {{c, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, b}}
>
> {{d, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, d}}
>
> {{e, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, c}}
> ```

Is it possible to make `Partition[l, 3, 1, {2, 2}, ?????]` returning `{{a, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7}, {6, 7, b}}`?

Comment: With regards to the last part of your question, this works too: `Partition[l, 3, 1, {2, 2}, {"", b, a}] `

Comment: @M.R. It doesn't work if `l = Range[8];`.

Comment: Sure, `Partition[Range@n,3,1,2,Join[Table[1,Floor[(n-1)/2]-1],{b,b,a}]]`. This is about the same as @MichaelE2 answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think these explain it, if one thinks about the elements that extend beyond limits of `Range[7]`:

```
{Range[-1, 7 + 1],
  Flatten@Table[{a, b}, 5]} // Grid

{Range[-2, 7 + 2],
  Flatten@Table[{a, b, c}, 4]} // Grid

{Range[-3, 7 + 3],
  Flatten@Table[{a, b, c, d}, 3]} // Grid
```

The following gives the desired outcome:

```
Partition[l, 3, 1, {2, 2}, 
 Append[ConstantArray[b, 1 + Length@l], a]]
```

A drawing that tries to highlight what I intended people to see in the second example. The 3,1 partition of overlapping sublists is a bit complicated to visualize, at least in my mind.

[image]

Comment: So, what is the algorithm? When the *`padlist`* is of length `n`, we prepend it *before*, and then add as many copies, as needed? How does it conform to the Documentation statement: "`Partition[list,{n[1],n[2],...,n[r]},klist,padlist]` effectively makes a depth-`r` array of copies of `padlist`, then superimposes list on them and partitions the result."?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  The 3,1-partitioning of array `l` in row 1 is padded according to the 3,1-partitioning of the a,b,c... array in row 2, which is a depth-1 array of copies of `{a,b,c,...}` (perhaps `Join[##, r] & @@ Table[{a, b, c}, 4]` with `r = 1` makes that clearer than `Flatten@Table[...]`).

Comment: I mean, the algorithm is that the array of copies of `padlist` is *anchored from the left* at the first element of the original list, and then padded from the left with `padlist`. The main point here is that the array of copies of `padlist` is anchored at (aligned by) the first element of the original list. It makes things clear, but I must say that the name `padlist` used in the documentation is wrong because this behavior has nothing common with usual *padding* performed by such functions as `ArrayPad` etc.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  I added a drawing to help explain. I think you already understood what I meant, though. I suppose there's some application in which the way `padlist` is used is convenient, but I found it confusing the first time I tried to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the illustration. It is sad that the Documentation doesn't provide an example illustrating this logic... I still can't imagine a real-world application of such behavior.